# Search Bar with Kaggle Data in Flask

Tags: flask, pycharm, menu, searchbar

I want to make a search bar in flask where I can show my movies from the database. The data I got is from kaggle.com. It's a Movie Recommendation System Website. I have already made the dropdown menu but my teacher wants me to create a search bar where I can show the desired movie.

I had made a search bar in html but I was not able to link it to my data.